# how to check if form has title and section before axios post autosaves

Tags: reactjs, axios

I got this task and I'm not quite sure how to do it.
Basically we have a form that has several feature that needed to be required, and I completed that part. But now I have to check before axios post autosaves the form if the title, section, subsection exits.

```
const onClickADD = () => {
    setLoader(true);
    apiService
      .post(`${APP_URL}/performance-review/questions/`, {
        title: title,
        question: quest,
        is_text: isText,
        is_hr_question: false,
        is_employee_question: false,
        is_client_question: false,
        is_team_lead_question: false,
      })
      .then(async () => {
        const result = await apiService.get(
          `${APP_URL}/performance-review/questions/`
        );
        var lastId = result[result.length - 1].id;
        let patchData = {
          id: param2.formId,
          add_questions: [lastId],
        };
        apiService
          .patch(`${APP_URL}/performance-review/pr-form/`, patchData)
          .then(() => setQuestionForms())
          .then(() => setTrigerChanges(true))
          .then(() => setOpenAddModal(false));
      });
  };
```

Comment: What are you checking the values for (truthy? equals something?) and what do you want to do after you check the values? First guess would be `if (!title) return;`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.